# Using scanf and fgets in the same program?

Tags: c, scanf

I need to do something like the following:

```
int main(void) {
char a,b,cstring;

printf("please enter something");
scanf("%c %c",&a,&b);
prinf("thanks, now some more");
fgets(cstring,35,stdin);

}
```

Problem is that whenever I enter the first vars from scanf, it skips to the end of the program. How do I do multiple inputs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first problem is that the `scanf()` reads two characters, but not the newline afterwards.

That means your `fgets()` reads the newline and finishes.

You are lucky your program is not crashing.  You tell `fgets()` that it is getting an array of 35 characters, but rather than passing an array, you pass the character (not the address of a character, even).  That also tells us you are not <s>including `#include <stdio.h>` (you can't use `scanf()` reliably according to the C standard without a prototype for `scanf()` in scope), and you are not</s> compiling with enough warnings enabled, or not paying enough attention to what your compiler is telling you.

You should be getting compiler warnings.  For example, GCC 4.6.0 says:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -g -I/Users/jleffler/inc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes \
     -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition xxx.c
xxx.c: In function ‘main’:
xxx.c:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘prinf’
xxx.c:8: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fgets’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

And, darn it, I hadn't even noticed the spelling mistake of `prinf()` for `printf()` until I tried linking and the compiler rubbed my nose in it by saying "Don't know what `prinf()` is!".

If your compiler doesn't at least give the second warning, get yourself a better compiler.

---

Comment:

> How do I stop it from reading the newline after it?

The problem is not stopping the `scanf()` from reading the newline; the problem is actually how to make it read it so that `fgets()` gets a clear run at the next line of input.  It actually is modestly tricky - one reason why I seldom use `scanf()` (but I often use `sscanf()`).  This does the job for simple inputs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char a,b,cstring[35];

    printf("please enter something");
    scanf("%c %c%*c", &a, &b);
    printf("thanks, now some more");
    fgets(cstring, 35, stdin);
    printf("OK: I got %c and %c and <<%s>>\n", a, b, cstring);
    return 0;
}
```

The `%*c` reads an extra character (a newline) without assigning it anywhere (that's because of the `*`).  However, if there are multiple characters after the second non-blank, it is no help.  I'd probably write a loop to read to the newline:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char a,b,cstring[35];
    int c;

    printf("please enter something");
    scanf("%c %c", &a, &b);
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        ;
    printf("thanks, now some more");
    fgets(cstring, 35, stdin);
    printf("OK: I got %c and %c and <<%s>>\n", a, b, cstring);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `getchar()` returns an `int` and not a `char`.  This reliably discards everything on the first line of input.  It also shows how to echo what you read - an important part of debugging.

Comment: sorry I am compiling with stdio. How do I stop it from reading the newline after it?

Comment: ohhh I understand. Thanks so much for taking the time to explain that.

Comment: @Wes: note that my code does not check that `scanf()` successfully read two characters; it should.  It should also check that `fgets()` got input too.  However, that would marginally clutter the answer, making it slightly harder for you to see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 2):

That's undefined behaviour. Your `cstring` variable, despite its name, is a single *character,* and you are attempting to read up to 35 characters into what its current value *points to*. In other words, the current character in `cstring` will be converted into a pointer and it will try to write your input there. That's going to be a memory location (most likely) between 0 and 255 inclusive.

That's what's causing your segmentation violation. Start with something like this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char a,b,cstring[99];

    printf("please enter something");
    scanf("%c %c",&a,&b);
    printf("thanks, now some more");
    fgets(cstring,35,stdin);

    return 0;
}
```

Or, possibly better:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char a,b,cstring[99];

    printf("please enter something");
    fgets(cstring,35,stdin);
    sscanf(cstring,"%c %c",&a,&b);
    printf("thanks, now some more");
    fgets(cstring,35,stdin);

    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you want a more robust solution for user input, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921). It's a tried and tested method with very good error checking.

Comment: Ah, so it should be a string type?

Comment: Or should i define it as char cstring[35] ?

Comment: @Wes: yes, see the update, you basically need to create an array large enough to hold the data you're trying to input.

Comment: @Wes, there is no string type in C, a  c string is simply a null-terminated character array

Comment: hrm, this exact code jumps to the end of the program after scanf()

Comment: That's because your scanf gets _two_ characters but the newline is still in the buffer. Meaning that the fgets will get that. You could use a getchar after the scanf to remove it but you'll still be caught out by edge cases. Seriously, follow the link and use a decent input function.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help - making sense now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when the flow reaches fgets(), this API first looks at stdin for input and it finds a stray '\n' there. As for fgets() which said that this API returns when it encounters EOF or '\n', since fgets() got '\n' from stdin so it executed without waiting for user to enter something as the APIs returning conditions met.

Solution to the problem is that you use getchar(); after scanf and ignore the extra characters left by scanf().
e.g:

```
scanf("%lf",&e);
getchar();
fgets(t,200,stdin);
```

or

other solution can be to use sscanf with fgets.
e.g:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int j;char t[200];
fgets(t,200,stdin);
sscanf(t,"%d",&j);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just use fflush(stdin) after using scanf which clears the issue

Comment: `fflush` is an output operation (it writes buffered data to the underlying stream). Using it on an input handle such as `stdin` has undefined behavior.

Comment: See [Using `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin) for a nuanced discussion of the merits and otherwise of using `fflush(stdin)`.