# Why does this code write input on second line?

Tags: c, io

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void main() {

    FILE* fp;
    char line[1024];
    char filename[1024];
    int length;
    int counter=0;

    while (1) {
       // fopen(filename, "w");
        int op = 0;
        printf("1. new file");
        scanf("%d", &op);
       
        switch (op) {

        case -1: break;
        case 1:
            
            printf("filename>>");
            scanf("%s", filename);
            length = strlen(filename);
            printf("length = %ld \n", strlen(filename));
            filename[length] = '.';
            filename[length + 1] = 't';
            filename[length + 2] = 'x';
            filename[length + 3] = 't';
            filename[length + 4] = '\0';
          
            fp=fopen(filename, "w");

            while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL)
            { 
                if (line[0] == 'q' || line[0] == 'Q')
                {
                    printf("end of line \n");
                    fclose(fp);
                    break;
                }
                else
                    fputs(line, fp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I made this code to make text file with what I want.
but the problem is,
when I run this program, it writes input starting from the second line, not
the first.

Why is this happening?
I want to write input starting from the first line.
How to change this code to write on the first line?

Comment: I had read that but I can't understand fully.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%s", filename);
```

When you input the name of file from keyboard, you type the filename then hit ENTER. The `scanf` function read `filename` but does not consume the ENTER character. Then when you use `fgets`, it will read this ENTER character then write a blank line into your file.

To solve this problem, you can use `getchar()` after `scanf("%s", filename);` to consume the enter character. You should add `1023` before `%s` in `scanf` function: [Disadvantages of scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf).

```
scanf("%1023s", filename);
getchar();
```

Or you can use `fgets` instead:

```
fgets(filename, sizeof(filename), stdin);
```

One more thing, the `break` in `switch` statement does not help you to quit the first `while` loop (`while (1) {...}`). You should use one condition to exit this loop, for example:

```
char ch = 'a';
while (ch != 'q') {

  ...
  switch (op) {
      case -1: ch = 'q'; break; // type -1 will exit the first while loop.
```

The `switch` should have the `default` case for the exception.

```
 switch (op) {
    ...
    default:
       // handle the exception here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely reason is that you are using fgets just after scanf on standard input.

See [Using scanf and fgets in the same program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546874/using-scanf-and-fgets-in-the-same-program).